# SQL Server 2005 Full-text search: Noise Words

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search

Using ContainsText, If I search: "Report Part 1" in quotes it returns the correct result (Report Part 1). However, if I search: Report Part 1 it gives me zero results.

My understanding was that full-text would take out the 1 as a noise word, and then do a search for contains Report and Part. I assumed that the results would give me Report Part 1, Report Part 2, etc, not zero results.

Can anyone give me insight as to why full text search is working this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be due to SQL Server filtering out searches with noise words. What happens if you enable 'transform noise words'?

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'transform noise words', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

This makes SQL Server transform all noise words in your query to a '*'.

Comment: I suppose I should have come back and said I found the answer, but you're spot on! My query was being transformed to "'Report' and 'Part' and '1'", but 1 was being removed, so you're left with an incomplete query which fails to run